# How to move files attached to mail to a VM on Azure

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

so I'm new to Azure and I need to create a service that when given an office365 email (subscriber) will Automatically move files attached to new mails 
of the subscriber to VM on azure and then run some tests on them there (inside the VM).
The only way I found to implement it so far is creating a logic-app for each subscriber which is done manualy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey buddy and welcome to StackOverflow. You should look for a decent tutorial instead of asking this question here on SO. A quick google search on you behalf led me to: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Microsoft-Azure-Tutorials

This is a dedicated channel for Azure tutorials. Thats your ticket. Good luck!

Comment: what kind of test are you gonna do > could you do your test using an azure function ?

Comment: I think so. All I need is to get remote control and transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

Few things if you want to get started.

1. Create the logic app that stores attachments to the database when a new email is received for a specific user
2. Add some parameters to your logic app so user email/credentials/tenant are not hard coded.
   https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd
3. Create an ARM Template to deploy this logic app.
4. Create another logic app that will deploy the previous logic app.
5. Whenever a new user is created, call the second logic.

Also do you really need to store your files in a database ? As an alternative you can use Azure Blob Storage to store all these files.

**EDIT**
If you need to move the files to a VM, I would suggest you to do this:

- When you receive an email

  1. Store the attachments in Blob storage.
  2. Generate a SAS Token (with Read permission)
  3. Put the URL + Sas Token of your file into aan Azure Servicebus Queue.
  4. On the VM, Have a service that reads messages from the queue and download files.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for answering my question. I actually need to move those files one by one to VM(s) on azure and run some tests on them there. I thought storing them in a DB would be easier to make the appropriate Function-App trigger and run 
the scripts inside the VM using WinRM. 
Just one last thing, I'd like to get more explanation about step 2 because I couldn't find how it can be done.

Comment: You can have a look at this article: https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Comment: also why are you copying file to VM ??  Could you please edit your question to add more explanation please?

Comment: Thank you again. Just a few last questions:

Comment: 1. As i understand, the conncetion to the subscriber mail is through "connection" which is placed inside connnections directory. so for deploying a logic-app for each subscriber I need to create such "connection" ? I stil can't understand how to parameterize the going to be deployed logic-app (specific for "triggred when a new mail arrive" logic-apps).

Comment: 2. Just to make sure, this design of the system ensure that it will be able to function fully automatically (starting from the arrival of a new mail until the sending of the results of the tests - by mail for example - including the registration to the system)?

Comment: yeah I guess azure is storing credentials internally